# Find first <a> tag whose href matches regex

Tags: javascript, regex, xpath

I'm building a chrome extension, and one thing this extension does is to look for the first `<a>` tag in the current page whose `href` attribute matches a given regex. JS only.

I have a several solutions in mind, I tried them, but each time, the page freezes because of the solution I tried (i.e. if I comment the lines doing this logic, the pages loads correctly). So I need a **fast** solution.

Here is what I tried:

**Solution 1: Xpath**

```
var reg = something;
var result = document.evaluate(
    '//*[local-name()="a"][contains(@href, "rss") or contains(@href, "feed")]', //first filtering
     document, null, 0, null
);

var item;
while (item = result.iterateNext()) {
    if (item.href.matches(reg)) // second and real filtering
    return item.href;
}
```

Page freezes.

**Solution 2: Xpath using matches()**

```
var result = document.evaluate(
    "//*[local-name()='a'][matches(@href, my_regex)]", //first filtering
     document, null, 0, null
);

var item;
while (item = result.iterateNext()) {
    return item.href;
}
```

I tried to hardcode my_regex between ''s, but I got an error in the chrome console (not a valid Xpath expression). Even putting some as simple as `[matches(@href, 'rss')]` gives the same error. Suspecting something related to xpath 1.0 or 2.0, but didn't investigate too long

**Solution 3: document.body.innerHTML.match()**

```
if (url = document.body.innerHTML.toString().match(reg)[0])
    return url;
```

Page freezes.

So now I have not so many ideas left, maybe try to investigate using the xpath's match(), but that's basically all. Any thoughts from you guys?

Comment: Do you really need a full regular expression, or are you just matching a simple string? In the latter case, you could use `document.querySelector` with an attribute selector.

Comment: Not enough text for an answer: `Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href]"), function(el) { return el.href.match(reg); })[0]`

Comment: @Malk: page freezes too :(

Comment: @Barmar: yes, the regex is something like this: `/(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*(feed|rss).*(\/|.xml)?/`

Comment: There might be something else going on. Even with 200,000 links the find call does not noticeably hang [http://jsfiddle.net/95TEp/]. Maybe you have this running inside a loop? You should recreate the situation in a fiddle.

Comment: Ok, simplifying the regex solved the freezing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that you can adapt to look for strings, regexps or both:

```
var string_match = "";
var regexp_match = new RegExp("www.*", "i");

var filter = {
    acceptNode: function(node){
        if((node.nodeType === 1) && (node.tagName === "A")){
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }
    }
}

var tree_walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, filter, false);

while(tree_walker.nextNode()){
    if(tree_walker.currentNode.href === string_match){
        console.log(tree_walker.currentNode);
        break;
    }else if(regexp_match.test(tree_walker.currentNode.href)){
        console.log(tree_walker.currentNode);
        break;
    }
}
```

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59vFt/2/

I'm using [document.TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) which I *think* is more asynchronous that getting element tags and stuff, although that will also work.

Btw, `innerHTML` is terrible - try to avoid using it :P